# How to speed up the initialisation of many spatially arranged "tiles"?

Tags: python, performance, vectorization, pyglet

I am using pyglets vertex_lists and batches to draw many squares all in a grid (not important). However I am finding that initialising all of the squares (which are Tile instances) takes a very long time using this double for loop method. I am not sure if this is overhead due to class instancing or due to doing it in a nested for loop. I am not sure how to determine that through profiling which is why I am asking here.

Once everything is initialised it works flawlessly with no performance issues (aside from the cocos actions not working but that is another problem).

I was looking into vectorisation but I wasn't sure if that would help here.

```
class Tile(layer.Layer):
    def __init__(self, batch, x, y, r, g, b, a = 255, width = 32, height = 32):
        super().__init__()

        self.vertex_list = batch.add(4, gl.GL_QUADS, None,
                        ('v2i\static', (x, y, x+width, y, x+width, y+height, x, y+height)),
                        ('c4B', (r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a, r, g, b, a)))

class Map(layer.ScrollableLayer):
    """The representation of the boards map area. Contains all tiles."""
    def __init__(self, width, height, cell_width = 32, cell_height = 32):
        super().__init__()

        batch = graphics.Batch()

        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                col = (random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), random.randrange(255), 255)
                cell = Cell(tile_batch, x*cell_width, y*cell_height, *col, cell_width, cell_height)

        self.batch = batch
```

If I wanted to create a map with a width and height of 1000x1000 it takes over a minute to do but once done has no issues keeping up.

Comment: If initialization is the problem, and assuming your `Cell` and your `Tile` class are similar, I would guess that the 1000 x 1000 calls to `batch.add()` are slowing down your code as the `Batch` object has to keep expanding piece by piece and append each tile's data. The reason why it has no issues keeping up afterwards is probably that your are doing all of your drawing in a single `batch.draw()` call. I would try to restructure your code so that **`batch.add()` is only called a single time to pass in all of your tile data**.

Comment: I am completely new to this pyglet.graphics stuff I had no idea you could add multiple in one go. I looked at the documentation and I can't see how to accomplish that? It only shows the form Batch.add(count, elf, count, mode, group, *data). Do you mean to add all the vertices in one go? That may cause problems as I want to change tiles independently later on.

Comment: I personally have not used pyglet, but yeah I meant adding all of the vertices in a single go. Looking through the `Batch` class [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pyglet/api/pyglet.graphics.Batch-class.html), there does not seem to be an obvious way to set a range of batch data with new data. I see that whenever you call `batch.add` you get a vertex list. Perhaps when you do partial updates to change tiles independently, you can modify the returned `VertexList's` `vertices` property? Not sure if that updates the data on the GPU side though...

Comment: I might give that a go. I do believe that modifying it does cause the update however I am a bit concerned about having such a huge vertex list and only making small changes at a time. Also might get very messy. However it is a good idea worth investigating, thank you.